# Data Collection Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I Use DataCollection on `SSMA\Object Explorer\Management\DataCollection` in 2 day ago.

[image]

But each time I get report from `Data Collection`, no data available to display. The following image is a sample `Server Activity History` report of data collection reports.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query will confirm if a snapshot was actually taken on that date: (change the name of your Data Management Warehouse)

```
SELECT [snapshot_time_id]
      ,[snapshot_time]
  FROM [DATA_MANAGEMENT_WAREHOUSE].[core].[snapshot_timetable_internal]
  WHERE CAST(snapshot_time AS DATE) = CAST('2014-06-19' AS DATE)
```

if there is no result set, run without the filter to confirm when the snapshots first started and what the interval is.

```
SELECT [snapshot_time_id]
      ,[snapshot_time]
  FROM [DATA_MANAGEMENT_WAREHOUSE].[core].[snapshot_timetable_internal]
```

Then, if you have no results, check to see if the Agent service is on. I believe it could be related to one of these things.

EDIT: added another query to check for wait stats.

```
SELECT [wait_type]
      ,[waiting_tasks_count]
      ,[wait_time_ms]
      ,[signal_wait_time_ms]
      ,[collection_time]
      ,[snapshot_id]
  FROM [DATA_MANAGEMENT_WAREHOUSE].[snapshots].[os_wait_stats]
```

Comment: I execute first your query and have 56 rows in result.

Comment: I've made an edit. can you try running the last query to see if wait_stats were generated for that date ?

Comment: don't exists any record in result on Wait_Stats query.

Comment: go into the properties of Server Activity, check the data collection frequency, and data retention settings, also, check the Agent Logs, maybe there was some errors during the collection at these times.